# Specify sorting in wildmenu list?

Tags: vimrc, options, wildmenu

EDIT

per accepted answer below, I have the following:

```
function! MySortDirEnts(ent1, ent2)
  if a:ent1[strchars(a:ent1)-1] == '/' && a:ent2[strchars(a:ent2)-1] != '/'
    return -1
  elseif a:ent1[strchars(a:ent1)-1] != '/' && a:ent2[strchars(a:ent2)-1] == '/'
    return 1
  else
    return a:ent1 == a:ent2 ? 0 : a:ent1 > a:ent2 ? 1 : -1
  endif
endfunction
function! MyListDirEnts(A, C, P)
  return join(sort(getcompletion(a:A, 'file'), "MySortDirEnts"), "\n")
endfunction
command -complete=custom,MyListDirEnts -nargs=1 Medit
```

Sorting algo needs some tweaks though, as currently it sorts by directory character length as opposed to alphabetically

---

I have the following in `.vimrc`

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest,list
```

(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names) for inspiration)

I would like to group directories first (I do this in zsh with `alias ls='gls --group-directories-first -F -a'`) (see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300615/group-directories-first-option-for-ls-command) for discussion of using coreutils `gls`)

Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

You can't get the behavior you describe by setting an option, if that's what you are asking.

If you *really* want it, you will have to write your own wrappers for the Ex commands you use the most and handle the sorting yourself. See `:help :command-completion-custom` for a couple of simple examples.

In your custom command, you can use `:help getcompletion()` to get the list of suggestions that you can then sort according to your requirements. See also `:help list-functions` for all the methods you can use on a list.

FWIW, if I were to work on this problem I would start by figuring out how to do the desired sorting and then work my way up to the command definition.

Comment: I put my solution thus far above - thoughts on why the sorting fn isn't behaving as expected?

Comment: Your snippet appears to work as intended, here.

Comment: interesting - mine seems to be sorting by _length_...

Comment: Oh I see the issue - it sorts by length first then by directory, so `~/Desktop/abc.txt` gets sorted after `~/Desktop/dir1ab/` but _before_ `~/Desktop/longsubdirname/`

Comment: Interesting indeed, I may have tried it on an accidentally correct sample. You are on the right path. Keep it up.

Comment: Ugh I would have to manually do wildcards and fuzzy finding wouldn't I... time to see how much I really want this hehe